# High CPU usage on Azure SQL Server ~1.6m rows

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, azure-sql-database

I'm currently running into an issue with one of our databases in Azure where 1 table is forcing us to scale the entire database up to cope with the CPU requirements. The basic structure of the table is as follows:

[image: Table Diagram]

**column_a** is unique and not nullable. **column_b** can be null.

This table has ~1.6 million rows in it so it's not a large table but it is used throughout the system we have built. We have several feeds pushing data in which requires an entry in this table so for each new request we receive there is a check for an entry and then if that doesn't exist one is created and the id returned. Once that data is received, we have subscribers which receive that data and use this table to link other information the system holds in a nice interface.

[image: Table of most expensive queries]

The table above shows the most expensive queries being run on this database over a 24 hour period. The one highlighted in yellow is `SELECT TOP (1) id FROM TableName WHERE column_a = @param1`.

Is this just bad database architecture or are we missing a trick to optimize for the number of reads we are performing on the table? Unfortunately, the number of reads being performed is only going to increase as we are adding new data feeds every month and we are aiming to have 5 - 10x the number of feeds by the end of this year.

Any help is much appreciated and my apologies if any of the above is unclear.

**Edit**

Create Table query

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableName](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [column_a] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [column_b] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [AK_Column_A] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [plate] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Edit 2**
Please understand that I have had to redact the names.
[image: Execution plan]

Comment: I've pulled the query directly from the Query Performance Insight on Azure. `SELECT TOP (1) id FROM TableName WHERE column_a = @param1` is being reported as the highest cost query being run in a 24-hour window as shown above

Comment: I've just taken a look and there is a plan which has a predicate of `CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(50), column_a, 0) = [@param1]` and has significantly higher costs associated

Comment: That’s it.  Someone is passing an NVARCHAR parameter, preventing index use.  Either fix the code or alter the column to NVARCHAR(50).

Comment: In that 'output list', isn't that a column that needs to be added as part of an include of an index? Some details here: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-query-execution-plans-beginners-non-clustered-index-operators/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there is a plan which has a predicate of CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(50), column_a, 0) = [@param1]

Someone is passing an NVARCHAR parameter, preventing index use. Either fix the code or alter the column to NVARCHAR(50).  Comparing a VARCHAR parameter to a NVARCHAR column is not problematic, as NVARCHAR has higher [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=%20SQL%20Server%20uses%20the%20following%20precedence%20order,%29%2028%20char%2029%20binary%20%28lowest%29%20More%20), so the parameter is converted instead of the column.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the issue is the # of executions. When u take the time per execution for two first rows, its about 0.8 seconds per row. But the select is executed so often It eats up cpu by comparision.

In adition, what is the datatype of @param?

Comment: I originally commented stating it was a varchar however I have since checked and it is indeed nvarchar. I have added the execution plan to my original post also.

Comment: There is your solution. Make whatever is executing that code to do it with the right datatype, varchar instead of nvarchar. Or change the data type in the table.